# Dúvidas com relacionamentos no Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Pessoal estou fazendo um `belongsToMany` para recuperar vários `Users` que estão relacionados a um `Item`.

Ele me retorna no array todos os `Users` corretamente, porem eu preciso fazer um `hasOne` de cada `User`(criei no model `User` um método pra isto), pois existe uma *foreignKey* `tipo` que define o tipo do `User`, e a descrição está na outra tabela.

Como faço? Quando dou `User::find(1)` consigo fazer o `hasOne`, mas quando faço `Item::find(1)` e pego os `Users` não consigo pegar o método do model `Users` que `hasOne`.

Class User:

```
class User extends Model {
   //The database table used by the model.
   protected $table = 'usuarios';

   //tipo de usuario
   public function tipoUser(){
       return $this->hasOne('App\TipoUser', 'id', 'tipo');
   }

   public function itens(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'usuarios_itens', 'id_usuario', 'id_item');
   }
}
```

Class Item:

```
class Item extends Model{
   protected $table = 'itens';

   protected $fillable = ['quantidade', 'valor'];

   public function pedido(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Pedido', 'id_pedido', 'id');
   }

   //Retorna os usuarios baseado no Model User
   public function usuarios(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'usuarios_itens', 'id_item', 'id_usuario');
   }
}
```

Retorno de Item::find(2)->usuarios;

```
{
   id: 1,
   email: "xxxx@xxxx.com",
   nome: "Fulano de Tal",
   tipo: 1,
   created_at: "2015-05-14 22:10:15",
   updated_at: "2015-05-15 23:03:09",
   pivot: <Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot #000000005707178a0000000021afac2b> {
       id_item: 2,
       id_usuario: 1
   }
}
```

no indice tipo, eu preciso que me retorne

```
tipo: {
   id: 1,
   descricao: "Administrador",
   created_at: "0000/00/00 00:00:00",
   updated_at: "0000/00/00 00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Ao fazer `Item::find(1)->users()` você está iterando (loop) entre os usuários?

Comment: Nao entendi! Editei o que retorna para mim quando faço Item::find(2)->usuarios;

Comment: o que te retorna se você fizer: `dd(Item::find(1)->usuarios())`

Comment: está editado!!!

Comment: Existe algum problema com as respostas? Você poderia nos dar um feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `with` para poder carregar os relacionamentos. Quando você converte para `JSON`, essa é a melhor maneira de poder carregar os dados relacionados.

Há duas formas:

```
Item::find(2)->usuarios()->with('tipoUser')->get();
```

OU

```
Item::with('usuarios.tipoUser')->find(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

O que você deve fazer é dizer que além dos **itens** você quer o **tipoUser dos usuários**, e isso você faz utilizando o método `with()`.

```
Item::with('usuarios.tipoUser')
    ->find($id);
```

Há também alternativas utilizando o **joins** ou até mesmo o **Query Builder**, mas creio que essa seja a mais simples.